# Отрисовка изображений в опере

Tags: jquery, javascript

Господа, вот у меня есть сайт с альбомом ретушь и там по наведению на конпку BEFORE оригинал фотки заменяется на фотку до ретуши (назову ее BEFORE), делается это с помощью js, но проблема в том, что отрисовка фотки BEFORE в ОПЕРЕ (и только в ней) происходит с мельканием. Предзагрузка фотки BEFORE естественно имееццо. Понятно, что опера как-то по -особому отрисовывает изображения, но есть ли какие-то решения этой проблемы мелькания при смене фоток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть вариант - отображать фотку AFTER над BEFORE. Тогда по нажатию кнопки, слой AFTER скрывается и, по идее, без мельканий отображается слой BEFORE.

**Добавлено 01.08.11**
Плюс этого подхода - в возможности включить плавное изменение изображения посредством javascript. Если надо просто поменять изображение, то читайте ниже про css-спрайты.
П.С. Ну, или почитайте про предзагрузку изображений, но это уже немного устаревший способ.

Comment: То есть в два слоя, а потом верхний слой в инвизибл?

Comment: Именно.

Comment: Идея хорошая, но потребление памяти вырастет...

Answer (score 2):

Используйте спрайты: вот [пример](http://www.1two.ru/css-sprites.html).

Comment: Преимущество - никакого js, чистый css. Вообще спрайты - хороший тон в вёрстке :)